# How do I get TextMate to see "require" expressions in CoffeeScript when compiling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textmate, coffeescript

When writing CoffeeScript in TextMate and wanting to use a 3rd party Javascript library like jQuery or Raphael there is a need to add a "require" like so:

```
$ = require 'jquery'
```

This works fine when using `coffee -c myfile.coffee` from the commandline, but fails in the TextMate bundle when trying to compile with this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
at require (module.js:346:19)
at Object. (.:3:7)
at Object. (.:4:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
at Object.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script.js:62:19)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/command.js:120:29
at Socket. (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/command.js:154:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:61:17)
```

In this example, the code is all in the same directory at the root of the project.

The same occurs when specifying:

```
$ = require 'jquery.js'
```

How are other people compiling in CoffeeScript with the TextMate bundle? This would seem to be a showstopper to me for anything but the most trivial code. Apart from syntax highlighting, surely this is one of the most important parts of this bundle?

Answer (score 3):

You've hit the "Run" command (⌘R), equivalent to `coffee myfile.coffee`.

You want "Compile and Display JS" (⌘B), equivalent to `coffee -c --print --bare myfile.coffee`. This should open up a window with the compiled output

```
var $;
$ = require('jquery');
```

As to `require`-ing libraries like jQuery and Raphael, I hope you understand that `require` is just a runtime function for loading modules; it has no compile-time meaning. You may be coming from a language like C++ or Java where there's a "linker." In CoffeeScript, on the other hand, code is compiled to JavaScript one file at a time, and JavaScript files are loaded individually into the runtime environment (be it a browser or a framework like Node.js).